# why is my PHP session expiring prematurely?

Tags: php

According to Chrome, my site's PHPSESSID cookie expiration is set to

```
Expires:    Monday, November 26, 2012 2:46:39 PM
```

But the session expires after only a few hours. I am calling session_start() on each page. Reading solutions offered for similar questions, I tried setting

`ini_set("session.cache_expire",300*24*60*60);`

and

`ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime",100*24*60*60);`

prior to `session_start()` but this did not solve the problem. (Their initial values are set to 180 and 1440 respectively.)

I'm on a shared server, and another suggestion was to change the default tmp directory so it's not root (where some garbage collection process might be deleting the cookies), so I did this with

```
$docroot = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$tmpdir = "$docroot/tmpx";
session_save_path($tmpdir);
```

This does not solve the problem. (I also have the same problem in other browsers, not just Chrome.) What else might I be doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** I saved the file for my current session locally, then tried logging in a few hours later. While the PHPSESSID cookie in Chrome (ie, the cookie whose content is this session file's name) remains stored with a date 100 days in the future as expected, the actual session file on the server now contains no data. (It exists but it is 0 bytes instead of 192 bytes as previously.) So it looks like the session file is not getting deleted, but the contents are getting erased.

Comment: try changing the values in php.ini or in your httpd.conf file.  Some settings can not be set by ini_set(), and that may be one of them

Comment: Have a look at the Cookie your browser gets from your server. Also, the sessions might be purged by cron on some linux distributions, I think.

Comment: @alecwhardy: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php -- The basic session stuff all is PHP_INI_ALL.

Comment: @alecwhardy I used ini_get() to check the values after I set them with ini_set(), and got values of 25920000 and 8640000 for session.cache_expire and session.gc_maxlifetime respectively, so it does look like ini_set() is setting the values.

Comment: @PhilippGrassl I looked at the expiration date of the cookie in Chrome, and it does appear to be correct (100 days in the future).

Comment: make sure you that ini_set() is the first thing after the opening <?php tag.  If that still doesn't work, just try setting the values in your .htaccess file.  Your web server may have disabled overriding the php ini settings, even though the values appear to be changes.

Comment: If that doesn't help, try clearing your temp directory on the server, setting a new one (and giving it the correct permissions), and using a new browser to test it.  Be sure to clear your browsers cache and cookies.

Comment: @alecwhardy I found out something interesting. I saved the file for my current session locally, then tried logging in a few hours later. While the PHPSESSID (with content being this session file's name) remains stored with a date 100 days in the future, the actual session file on the server now contains no data. (It exists but it is 0 bytes instead of 192 bytes as previously.) So it looks like the session file is not getting deleted, but the contents are getting erased. I am wondering if this might narrow down the source of the problem. (I'll update the question with this info.)

Comment: @alecwhardy I edited .htaccess as per your suggestion and confirmed the changes are registering as the local values, so now I'll have to wait and see if that fixes it and report back.

Comment: if the contents of your session data are being erased, then the problem sounds server side.  If you are hosting the site on your own server, try reinstalling your HTTP server and checking that your permissions are correct.  

Alternatively, you could try testing your code locally using a temporary testing server.  That would help narrow down the problem as to if its server side or a bug in your code.

Comment: Also, this probably isn't the problem, but if you are redirecting to and from different pages on your website, make sure that each page you redirect to has session_start() before any of the headers are sent.  Try enabling error reporting and see if you are getting and session errors, because blank session files sounds like the data never got written in the first place.

Comment: Have you had a look at your cron tables? I still believe that there might possibly be a session-purging job. And: Make sure that you use the ini_set in **every** PHP-file before session_start()! See [here](http://us.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime). Also, have you tried setting the lifetime in php.ini itself?

Comment: @alecwhardy editing .htaccess appears to have solved the problem (2 days now and the session is getting retained). I also realized after you brought it up that I do have a single redirect page I had forgotten about (actually a form submitted via javascript that calls session_start() without changing the default session values, but basically what you mean). So if I am not misunderstanding, it seems that when someone submitted this form, the default values cause sessions older than 3 hours to be removed. (I'm still not sure why the sessions just get emptied to 0 bytes rather than deleted.)

Comment: @alecwhardy perhaps you can copy your answer about .htdocs and the redirect issue and paste as an official answer, and I will mark it correct for future viewers.

Comment: @PhilippGrassl I did check the cron. (That's a good call because I had this problem before on a shared server where they had a cron script doing garbage collection, but this time that doesn't seem to be the issue.) It looks like the problem was I had a script getting called via javascript that I had forgotten about, which was calling session_start() without changing the relevant values from the php.ini defaults. I changed the defaults via .htdocs so I don't run into a similar issue in the future.

Comment: Glad to have helped.  I will make it an official answer.

Comment: And you are correct.  When ever session_start (or any other similar function) is called, it uses the default values unless they are changed before the function is called.  If you redirect to another page that does not set the values (in this case, the session life), it uses the default value.  By setting the session lifetime in your .htaccess, you are changing the default values site-wide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many possible reasons why session data is not being correctly handled.  Most likely,  the session is not being started on EVERY page that is loaded and uses the data.  To fix this, make sure that session_start() is started on every single page that is called or redirected to.  Also, if you make any changes to the session configuration (ex, ini_set()), make sure that that is applied either globally or on each any every page.  To apply it globally, add

```
php_flag session.gc_maxlifetime <your value>
php_flag session.cache_expire <your value>
```

to your .htaccess file.  Alternatively, you can add

```
ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime", <value>);
ini_set("session.cache_expire", <value>);
```

directly before session_start() on every page that calls session_start().

Comment: I found a gotcha with setting session.gc_maxlifetime via the ini_set function rather than in php.ini.  On Ubuntu 14.4, perhaps all debian variants, a cron job was periodically scanning all php.ini files it could find, and extracting the biggest value for gc_maxlifetime. That value was then used to delete any files that had a modified time longer ago than that value.  The upshot is that the value from php.ini is used, rather than what you set with ini_set.  Symptoms were still having a cookie, but no session file.

Answer (score -1):

Add this before `session_start()`:

```
ini_set('session.use_cookies', 1);
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 300*24*60*60);
```

File-based sessions may be broken on your system, for any number of reasons. Try using database-based sessions and see if that fixes  things.